# uniform convergence of linear functions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $X^*$ be its topological dual, and let $K\subseteq X$ be closed convex and bounded. Let $(x_n^*)\subseteq X^*$ be an equicontinuous sequence on $K$ and assume that every $x_n^*$ attains its supremum on $K.$ Assume further that $(x_n^*)$ converges pointwise to $0.$

Then $(x_n^*)$ converges uniformly to $0?$

What happens if we replace the assumption of sequence by nets, i.e. instead of $(x_n^*)$ we take a net $(x_i^*)$ and we assume moreover that $(x_i^*)\cup \{0\}$ is weakly* compact in $X^*$?

Answer (score 2):

No. $X=\ell_2$, $K$ the unit ball and $x_n^*=e_n$, i.e. $x_n^*(x)=x_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was fast. Thank you. What happens if we replace the assumption of sequence by nets, i.e. instead of $(x_n^*)$ we take a net $(x_i^*)$ and we assume moreover that $(x_i^*)\cup \{0\}$ is weakly* compact in $X^*$?

Comment: Since $e_n=x_n^* \to 0$ in the weak$^*$ topology, $\lbrace e_n:  n\in\mathbb N \rbrace \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is weak$^*$-compact. If the statement is wrong for sequences there is no hope for nets.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your fast answer.